# What are the specific cases that justify Spring selection over Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, comparison

I've found quite a huge pile of topics that give the answer for the opposite question: "Why choose Spring Boot over Spring?", but I guess somebody can give an example that will justify Spring selection over Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can found several [cons on Spring boot over Spring](https://rabbitstack.github.io/spring/spring-boot-or-not-to-spring-boot/), mainly missing learning steps in Spring and support and if using monolithic application

> **If you are new to Spring and want to learn how the dependency injection, AOP programming, and proxies work**, starting with Spring Boot is not a good choice. Spring Boot hides the most of these details from you.
>
> If you are not familiarized with other projects of the Spring ecosystem (Spring Integration, Spring AMQP, Spring Security, etc), using them from **Spring Boot will make you miss a lot of concepts**
>
> In a large and **monolithic based applications, I wouldn’t encourage you to use Spring Boot**

Also can [increase deployment size](http://www.java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/spring-boot-pros-and-cons/)

> Spring boot may unnecessarily increase the deployment binary size with unused dependencies.